# ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Aborted by user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-run

This is the error I am facing while trying to deploy a flask app to google cloud run through github action.The error messages and the .yml I am running is pasted below.

```
Run gcloud run deploy $REPO_NAME \
  gcloud run deploy $REPO_NAME \
  --region $REGION \
  --image gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA \
  --platform "managed" \
  --quiet
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    PROJECT_ID: ***
    REGION: us-east1
    REPO_NAME: image-flix
    CLOUDSDK_AUTH_CREDENTIAL_FILE_OVERRIDE: /home/runner/work/Sigma_ImageFlix/Sigma_ImageFlix/gha-creds-------.json
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /home/runner/work/Sigma_ImageFlix/Sigma_ImageFlix/gha-creds-----.json
    GOOGLE_GHA_CREDS_PATH: /home/runner/work/Sigma_ImageFlix/Sigma_ImageFlix/gh------.json
    CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT: ***
    CLOUDSDK_PROJECT: ***
    GCLOUD_PROJECT: ***
    GCP_PROJECT: ***
    GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT: ***
    CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT: github-actions-setup-gcloud
##[debug]/usr/bin/bash -e /home/runner/work/_temp/9e460119-c08f-4202-ac61-3fcc42b0366b.sh
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Aborted by user.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have given all the permission still this issue is coming ?? Please help.

The mai.yml file is here :

```
name: image-flix

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main

env:
  PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
  REGION: us-east1
  # project-name but it can be anything you want
  REPO_NAME: image-flix

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    name: Setup, Build, and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Authenticate with Google Cloud
      - id: "auth"
        uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v0"
        with:
          credentials_json: "${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY_JSON }}"

      # Setup gcloud CLI/SDK
      - name: Set up Cloud SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0

      - name: Authorize Docker push
        run: gcloud auth configure-docker

      - name: Build and tag the docker image
        run: |-
          docker build . --tag gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA

      - name: Push the image to the Google Container Registry (GCR)
        run: |-
          docker push gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA

      - name: Deploy
        run: |-
          gcloud run deploy $REPO_NAME \
          --region $REGION \
          --image gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA \
          --platform "managed" \
          --quiet
```

The failure is occuring at the docker PUSH stage,docker build everything else is perfectly running.
And I am executing this file via **github action** , not using any extra command from outside.

Let me know if i have some access error for the service account.

Refer to this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdnAE.png)

Comment: Can you be clearer in the command that you run?

Comment: I have added some more details , please check.

Comment: Have you managed to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the image was in a different project.

I had eu.gcr.io/{project-name}/{project-name}/{hash} instead of

eu.gcr.io/{project-id}/{project-name}/{hash}

Run the generated command in your gcloud command line with --quiet disabled and see what error you get.